# Android:mount unmount and format sdcard

Tags: android, android-sdcard, usb-mass-storage

Is there any possibility given in Android Icecream-sandwich to programatically format,mount and unmount sdcard ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related API's are in `com.androidserver.MountService` (it's not new), but this class is hidden and not available for SDK applications. In theory, you can get the `MOUNT_FORMAT_FILESYSTEMS` permission (it is not a system permission), but you cannot use it since the API's are not public.

Comment: I am having the rooted device and have access to source code ,is there any possibility?

Comment: If you are building your own ROM, you can sign your apps with the system key and do pretty much anything. If you just have a routed device, you can request root access in a shell, and issue shell commands to mount/unmount, etc.

Comment: Of course: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html